# alias: backup & and edit file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, alias

I need to backup files (usually images) before editing (and overwrite) them.
Currently I do it by:

```
cp file.jpg ~/BACKUP/file.jpg
exiv2 BLABLABLA file.jpg
```

How can I do it with a single command?
e.g.

```
AAalias file.jpg
```

where `AAalias` is an alias or a function, doesn't matter but this is the *shape* I'm looking for: command + filename

Comment: define command.  single press of enter?

Comment: yes, I update OP

Comment: It's not really clear what is AAalias but @Kusalanada answer should work like bash alias and do it in single command.

Answer (score 3):

Using a shell function:

```bash
backup_and_edit () {
    cp -i "$1" "$HOME/BACKUP" &&
    exiv2 BLABLABLA "$1"
}
```

This would go where you usually put aliases and shell function (probably in your `~/.bashrc` file), and after having instantiated the function (by starting a new shell session), you would use it like

```
$ backup_and_edit ./some/file.jpg
```

When invoked like this, the function would execute

```bash
cp -i ./some/file.jpg "$HOME/BACKUP" &&
exiv2 BLABLABLA ./some/file.jpg
```

The `-i` option to `cp` would make the utility ask for confirmation before over-writing a file with the same name in your backup directory.  If the copy fails, the `exiv2` command would not be invoked.

Comment: I have this backup function: `backup() {
    for file in "$@";
    do
        local new="${file}.$(date '+%Y%m%d')";
        while [[ -f "$new" ]]; do
            new+="~";
        done;
        printf "copying '%s' to '%s'\n" "${file}" "$new";
        \cp -ip "$file" "$new";
    done;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias, that uses a function:

```
alias Aalias='_(){ local file=${@: -1};(($#<2))||[[ ! -e "${file}" ]]&&echo "Usage: Aalias <options> <file>"&&return 1;cp "${file}" ~/BACKUP/${file};exiv2 $@;}; _'

${@: -1} grabs the last argument for the file 
[[ ! -e "${file}" ]] checks to make sure the file exists
```

Usage will be shown if less than 2 arguments are provided or the file doesn't exist.

If the last argument is the name of a file that exists it will be backed up to the BACKUP directory in user's home and exiv2 will be launched with the options provided on the commandline.